Javascript / Ajax Get Request Seems to Stop Code or Form Post Request
I have a web page that is utilizing ajax to have my backend Python code calculate some values via GET and return them to javascript for html form display (getrate function) upon a button click.  This part seems to work ok but the next thing that should happen is the HTML form should be submitted via POST.  This does not happen when I call the function to calculate values first.  If I remove the function to calculate values, the POST works.
I have tried various ways to d this including both synchronous and asynchronous calls, etc.  Here is sample code of the code:
document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", function(){ufees(submitForm)}, true);

function ufees(callback) {
        getrate();
        callback();
}

function submitForm() {
        document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
}

function getrate() {
            // data to send back to the server
            var send = {
                category: category.val(),
                clientname: clientname.val(),
                billable: billable.val(),
                timeUser: timeUser.val()
            };


            $.getJSON("/time/rate", send, function (response) {
                document.getElementById("rate").value = (response.rate);
                document.getElementById("fee").value = (document.getElementById("hours").value * document.getElementById("rate").value).toFixed(2);
                if (response.edit_fee=='1') { document.getElementById("fee").removeAttribute('readonly'); };
                if (response.edit_fee =='0') { document.getElementById("fee").setAttribute('readonly', true); };
                //let edit = getfeeeditable.call();
            });
}



Looking for help to determine why the form POST isn't working.

"This does not happen when I call the function to calculate values first. If I remove the function to calculate values, the POST works." - Are there any errors on the browser's development console?  When you use the browser's script debugger to step through the code as it executes, what specifically happens?

The right place to invoke callback() is at the end of your getJSON success function (where you have something commented out).

@David, yes, there is an error:
time/:940 Uncaught ReferenceError: getrate is not defined
at ufees (time/:940:9)
at HTMLButtonElement. (time/:828:77)
ufees @ time/:940
(anonymous) @ time/:828

@BrandenColeman: Which line of the code shown produces that error?  getrate certainly appears to be defined here.  Is this function defined in global scope, or a more specific scope?

@David, your questions led me down a path to discover I had inadvertently nested  getrate() within another function thereby putting it out of scope I guess.  I corrected that, and everything works!  Thanks!

Can you share your HTML as well? Is the #add button part of the form and have you defined the type attribute for the button?

If the result of the calculation from the AJAX request is used immediately to do a POST request, why don't you just do the POST request and do the calculation on the back end after the form is submitted?
